# Can't use HG through a mounted directory

Tags: mount, nfs, sshfs, mercurial

I have a repository on my development server whose directory I have mounted using sshfs. I've synced up my uid/guid and seem to be able to execute/edit files as usual on said directory, as if I had just ssh'ed in. However, when I run a command like `hg status`, the process hangs and never returns to me the expected result. Is there any reason why mounting a directory like this would be much different than just sshing in and calling the same command?

For reference, the mounted filesystem is nfs, and the command I run is 'sshfs me@myserver:/home/me/repo /home/me/mnt/repo'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an "interesting" problem :-) I don't know mercurial, but (i) do you have any debugging options to hg? (ii) when hg hangs, can you still access the mounted filesystem, ls and cd working normally?

Comment: (i) Not that I know of. There is a --verbose option, but using that still returns me nothing. (ii) yes, I still have full accesss to the filesystem.

Comment: OK, two tools that might help you find out what hg is doing: `ltrace` and `strace` (see their man pages). Running them might give you an idea what is happening.

Comment: Ah, cool. So it seems that the issue isn't that hg hangs - it actually runs fine. However, it seems to be scanning the entire repository for changes remotely, resulting in excessively slow speeds. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: I see. Seems you better create a local copy -- since you are using a version control system, this is actually the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial doesn't require any special form of access to the files, but (as you've found out), it will stat all the files when you run `hg status`. With a network filesystem this can take a long time.

Since Mercurial is a **distributed** version control system, the basic assumption is that you'll be operation on a *local* repository, not a repository residing on a network filesytem. So you should always try to make a local clone and work on that.